# using color on input overwrites css placeholder color

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to assign some colors for a placeholder on an input like so:

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ccc; }
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ccc; }
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #ccc; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #ccc; }
```

but if I also assign a color to the input like:

```
input{color:#FF0000;}
```

Then the latter color is the one that takes precedence for both color and placeholder

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not seeing such behavior. It works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ABfuS We'll need to see your actual code. Make sure your `input` selector doesn't actually have any IDs or classes.

Comment: I notice, I use !important on placeholder colors and define the placeholder after the input definition in my stylesheets. I guess, that was the reason why - can't remember. Like this  :-moz-placeholder { color: #bbb !important; }

Comment: okay, using important fixed, have no idea why it's being overwritten though.  Firebug is hot showing me anything other than the color being crossed out.  Anyway, thanks.